# setContentView only large layout

Tags: android, android-activity, layout

My code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_items);
}
```

I have these layouts:

- activity_items.xml
- activity_items.xml (large)

When I run avd, I need that `setContentView` to use the large `activity_items`, but it uses the normal `activity_items`. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Create `layout-large` folder in `res` directory of your project and put that `activity_items.xml (large)` inside that , for more information check [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)